# why read() in c++ needs a pointer to char

Tags: c++

I have this line :

```
while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
```

Why do we need that the address be typecast to pointer to char?
Thanks in advance!

```
void display_sp(int n)
{
    account ac;
    bool flag=false;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\nBALANCE DETAILS\n";

    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nAccount number does not exist";
}
```

Comment: It emphasises that what you are doing is not portable code.

Comment: Because it's for reading raw unformatted characters. And it's not a good idea to serialize and deserialize as you do.

Comment: In summary, you shouldn't have to cast it; you should read it into your buffer and then process it

Comment: I should add that if account has a vtable or an internally allocated buffer, that's highly insecure code. Hard to mantain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, because of multiple reasons:

- Before [std::byte](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)(c++17) existed, the best type representing a byte was `char` or `unsigned char`. Here you are reading serialized data into your structure instance, you are not reading characters, so `char` in this context means byte not character.
- [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) was designed to read characters in general (you can even specify the character type by using `std::basic_ifstream` directly) and since a `char` might also be used to read bytes this was good enough to cover all situations without adding another interface for reading bytes, which means all of `std::ifstream` functions work with `char`s.
- Since `char` also represents a character, there is no implicit conversion from "all pointers" to `char*` while there is an implicit conversion from "all pointers" to `void*` because `void*` represents a generic pointer and nothing else, thus it is much safer to allow.
- C++ is a typed language which implies that within reason the action of going from one type to another should be explicit rather than implicit, especially when the action is not 100% safe.
- `reinterpret_cast` was mainly designed for this kind of usage. It is very much its reason to exist (among small other cases like integer to pointer conversion).

Now your case kind of sits at the border of all these reasons/principles and you could argue against each of them but that is the current situation of things that led to the fact that you have to use a `reinterpret_cast` to cast to `char*` in your example.